# Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' at ReactDOM.render

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have several years experience as a backend dev, but my frontend experience has been limited to very basic bugfixes in an established frontend codebase. So I have been trying to set up a "hello world" one page app using React Bootstrap so I can learn.

I attempted to just copy the set up in the React Bootstrap Basic Example [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/react-bootstrap/code-sandbox-examples/tree/master/basic-v5?file=/src/index.js), but I am getting the following console error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
> index.js:8:16

I have my current code available at [this github repo](https://github.com/rosemaryehlers/habits/tree/wip/service/src/public).

Pretty sure I've made some n00b mistake, but I guess a n00b has to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the browser does not support JSX sintax (IE: `<App />`). There is a lot of ways to get this working, but I recommend [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/)

More about JSX: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: So I actually got the ReactJS + Babel / JSX hello world working, using the script tag for the in-browser Babel compiler, but I took it out when I switched over to React Bootstrap. You can see what I had in my index.html at this commit: https://github.com/rosemaryehlers/habits/blob/5b5762f370f36a9a07c20a9f12839c8cbd5c02b5/service/src/public/index.html

I tried adding it back in but it looks like React Bootstrap does not work with the in-browser Babel compiler - is that correct?